# Accept only types, which declaring some interface

Tags: c#, oop, types, interface

How to do things like this

```
List<Type:IMyInterface> a = new List<Type:IMyInterface>;
a.Add(typeof(MyClass1)); //MyClass1..3 implementing IMyInterface
a.Add(typeof(MyClass2));
a.Add(typeof(MyClass3));
IMyInterface c = default(a[1]); //create MyClass2 object
a.Add(typeof(Object)); //must fail
```

without constructing object first or checking type later?

Comment: default(a[1]) will always return a `null`, you'll need to detail the use cases a little better.

Comment: `default(Type t)` must return object, created with default parameter-less constructor, if it exists. In my case `Type t` can be `typeof(MyClass1..3)`.

Comment: What should accept types only and why? What are you trying to do?

Comment: `default(a[1])` even will not be compiled (why not `Activator.CreateInstance` ? ). I suggest to implement your own collection aggregating `List<Type>` and verify type before adding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this if you know the types involved statically:

```
public class TypeList<T>
{
    private readonly List<Type> types = new List<Type>();
    public void Add<D>() where D : T, new()
    {
        this.types.Add(typeof(D));
    }

    public T NewAt(int index)
    {
        return (T)Activator.CreateInstance(this.types[index]);
    }
}
```

then you can do:

```
var a = new TypeList<IMyInterface>;
a.Add<MyClass1>();
a.Add<MyClass2>();
a.Add<MyClass3>();
IMyInterface c = a.NewAt(1);
a.Add<object>(); //won't compile
```

Answer (score 3):

what you want is not directly supported in C#. since Constraints on Type parameter can only be specefied on constructor, inheritance hierarchy, interface implementation and a few others. [more details](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx)

you can do it in a different way, however in this approach there is no compile time error:

public interface IMyConstraint
    {
        void Do();
    }

```
public class MyClass: IMyConstraint
{
    public void Do()
    {
    }
}

// Inherit from the List class to add some functionality to it
public class MyTypeList<T> : List<T> where T : System.Type
{
    public MyTypeList()
    {

    }

    // use new keyword to prevent client from using the List.Add method.
    public new void Add(T type)
    {
        // here you check if the type is implementing the interface or not
        if (!typeof(IMyConstraint).IsAssignableFrom(type))
        {
            // if it dose not implement the interface just throw an exception
            throw new InvalidOperationException();
        }
        // call the original List.Add method            
        base.Add(type);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank thou. That's complete answer.